# Averaging linear regression model coefficients with different data sources

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mean, linear, model

I am new to model averaging and its not clear on how to use the model average coefficients. I have data from three different data sources, (say A, B, and C) and the linear regression models for the three sets of data.

$ {Y_A} = \alpha_{A} + \beta_{1A} X_{A} + \epsilon_{A}$,
$ {Y_B} = \alpha_{B} + \beta_{1B} X_{B} + \epsilon_{B}$,
$ {Y_C} = \alpha_{C} + \beta_{1C} X_{C} + \epsilon_{C}$

I understand that the linear regression coefficients can be averaged to get model predictions. Is it valid to use the average coefficients in the individual models for prediction? For example, $\alpha$ is average of ($\alpha_{A}$,$\alpha_{B}$, and $\alpha_{C}$) and $\beta$ is average of $\beta_{1A}$, $\beta_{1B}$ and $\beta_{1C}$ and the final predictions are made use averaged coefficients as the following.

$ {Y_A} = \alpha + \beta X_{A} + \epsilon_{A}$,
$ {Y_B} = \alpha + \beta X_{B} + \epsilon_{B}$,
$ {Y_C} = \alpha + \beta X_{C} + \epsilon_{C}$

Can one use the averaged coefficients in the individual models? Thank you.